# Google Sheet Conditional Formula for IF function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Trying to make a Google Sheets Formula for Conditional Formula that when a cell in column "A" is equal to  then change the background to red if Cell in the matching row in column "E" is empty
I started with REGEXMATCH but I couldn't figure out how to format it.

[image: Excel]

Basically, if the company's names match they require a PO# in which it would mark the cell red if not filled out

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=($A2<>"")*($E2="")
```

apply it on range A2:A